# Getting the same error The type ''a list' does not match the type 'int' in F#

Tags: f#

I need your help for this one.. Im trying to run a simple F# programm but Im stuck with this error : The type ''a list' does not match the type 'int'. 
Here's the code:

```
let mutable q = 0
let mutable m = 0
let mutable k = 0
let mutable h = 0


printf("Enter the day:")
q <- System.Console.ReadLine() |> int
printf("Enter the month:")
m <- System.Console.ReadLine() |> int
printf("Enter the year:")
k <- System.Console.ReadLine() |> int
let j = k / 100

let h = (q + [(13*(m+1))/5] + k + [k/4] + [j/4] - 2*j) % 7



printfn "The day is: %int" h
System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Im just trying to get the value of "h". How does it work with "j" but not "h"? Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expression `[(13*(m+1))/5]`, `[` and `]` are used which is how F# identifies list, the expression should have used `(` and `)`, e.g.

```
let h = (q + ((13*(m+1))/5) + k + (k/4) + (j/4) - 2*j) % 7
```

See: [F# Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/lists)

Comment: Yes that was strange.. I am very new to the F#, so Im sorry for the stupid question. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @BillyFitt No need to be sorry. If you don't ask you can not learn.